# All capital letters in a new document

Tags: formatting, scrivener

Weird thing just happened. I added a new document to a manuscript and when typing, all letters are in caps. Caps lock is not on. It's not happening in any other app, just in Scrivener and just in a new document. I deleted the problem document, opened another an the same thing happened. I tried cutting/pasting lower-case characters from another document which worked, but still...it's annoying and I don't want it to keep happening. Any help in Scrivenerville?

Comment: It sounds like it might be a style problem - try checking there..  Shrug.

Comment: I know this was posted a year ago but I just wanted to say -- THANK YOU! I just experienced the same exact issue and it was driving me nuts. Thank you to the poster of the question and to the poster of the answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably in Script Mode.

In my version of Scrivener (Mac) you can press command-8 to switch back and forth between modes. (I.e. prone opportunity for mishaps...)

You should also be able to uncheck it by selecting: `Format > Scriptwriting > Script Mode`.

It should be checked if this is your problem.